# create a map with keys = fields names and values = query result

Tags: soql, map, dynamic-soql

I am trying to create a map from a result of a SOQL query,
this map contains the name of the fields as keys and the values of the query as values
for example:

> List accounts = [SELECT Name, Email FROM Account];

and the map Map has this structure:

```
key         value
name        123 
email       test@test.co.uk
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: *Why* do you need it to be a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `SObject` record has a very map-like structure by default.

```
Account record = [SELECT Name, Email FROM Account LIMIT 1];
system.debug(record.get('Name');
system.debug(record.get('Email');
```

It even supports `put`:

```
record.put('Email', 'newemailaddress@example.com');
```

However, if you absolutely must have a map for some reason, you can use serialization (a CPU intensive process) as follows:

```
String representation = JSON.serialize(record);
Map<String, Object> dataMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(representation);
dataMap.remove('attributes');
```

Answer (score 2):

SObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() does the job for you. From Summer '16 this feature is available to convert SObject class to map.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that it _converts_ the SObject into a `Map<String, Object>`, as the original SObject remains intact. It certainly takes a given `SObject` and generates/returns a `Map<String, Object>` though. I might just be nit-picking.