# How to put all the fields of a record in a map along with its values?

Tags: trigger, map

I have a trigger which fires after I insert a applicant record. In the trigger, I want all the fields entered by the applicant in the map as keys and their corresponding values as value in a map.

How to go about this?

If I create a map like `Map<String,Applicant__c>` it throws error for the decimal fields I have. Please help.  This is the code I have so far but it looks inefficient.

```
criteriaList=new LIST<CustBusinessPro__Criteria__c>([SELECT Id,Name,CustBusinessPro__Where_Clause__c FROM CustBusinessPro__Criteria__c] );

for (CustBusinessPro__Criteria__c cd: criteriaList) {

     for(CustBusinessPro__Applicant__c app:Trigger.new)
     {
         System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'+ cd.CustBusinessPro__Where_Clause__c);
         test=cd.CustBusinessPro__Where_Clause__c;
         test=test.replaceAll('AND','&&');
         test=test.replaceAll('OR','||');
         test=test.replaceAll('CustBusinessPro__Age__c',String.valueOf(app.CustBusinessPro__Age__c));
         test=test.replaceAll('CustBusinessPro__Salary__c',String.valueOf(app.CustBusinessPro__Salary__c));
         test=test.replaceAll(' CustBusinessPro__Country__c',app.CustBusinessPro__Country__c);
         test=test.replaceAll('CustBusinessPro__Gender__c ',app.CustBusinessPro__Gender__c);
         test=test.replaceAll('CustBusinessPro__Marital_Status__c ',app.CustBusinessPro__Marital_Status__c);
         test=test.replaceAll('CustBusinessPro__City__c ',app.CustBusinessPro__City__c);
         System.debug('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>value after replacing'+ test);

    }
}
```

Comment: ** Map<string,applicant__c>

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need a separate `Map`? An sObject record is effectively already a map of fieldName => fieldValue. If you have the API Name of a field, you can write `mySObjectRecord.get(<field's API name>);`

Comment: I have a filter logic stored in a string. I need to compare all the fields of the applicant whether they satisfy the logic.   I have a filter logic say: Age>20 AND salary<600000 .Now I want to replace the applicants values of age and salary here and check if it evaluates to true. How can I do this without a map?

Comment: Hi Jyoti, welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you post the code you've written, showing us where you get the errors, what's broken or where you're stuck, I'm confident you'll find plenty of people willing to assist you.

Comment: I don't see how the code you have posted relates to the question. You may find this answer helpful http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113244/how-to-fill-a-map-with-the-object-field-as-key-from-the-query/113249#113249. Just make it a Map<String, Object> and don't use the String.valueOf.

Comment: Hey I used the map logic you suggested but it gives me the map for all the records. How can I restrict it to a single record which fires the trigger?

Comment: If the trigger fires for one record then that is all you will get. If the trigger fires for multiple records you should be processing each record in turn inside the Trigger.new loop. If you are collecting some overall result you can keep the results in a list 9adding to the list each time round the loop).

Comment: The trigger fires only after one record is inserted.But still the debug logs show me all details of all records in the map.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Derek F you don't need to create the map as you can get a field value by using the field name (obtained in the code below through the describe API but you could hard code a list of field names if you are only interested in a few fields):

```
SObjectType sobType = CustBusinessPro__Applicant__c.SObjectType;
Set<String> fields = sobType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();

for (CustBusinessPro__Applicant__c app : Trigger.new) {
    for (String name : fields) {
        Object value = app.get(name);
        if (value != null) {
            // use name and value in your logic here
        }
    }
}
```